# Can I access native DOM elements without using `#` in templates

Tags: javascript, angular

I can access components in a component view using `@ViewChildren` decorator like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <alert type="info"></alert>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChildren(AlertComponent) alerts: QueryList<AlertComponent>
```

Is there any way to access DOM elements **with `@ViewChildren` decorator**  other then using `#` symbol in a template? Maybe some kind of `read` parameter flavor?

```
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div #divElement>Tada!</div>
  `,
})

@ViewChild("divElement") div: any;
```

If not possible, please mention that in comments or an answer. Just want to know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The ViewChild decorator works only with `ComponentRef` or `ref`-variable**. The second parameter works against the already queried element. A pretty good answer is given here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35209681/324224

How the ViewChild is implemented can be seen in the Angular repo:

https://github.com/vicb/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/core/src/metadata/di.ts#L353

And based on the documentation and the tests:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/14ee75924b6ae770115f7f260d720efa8bfb576a/modules/%40angular/core/test/metadata/di_spec.ts

I am pretty sure that only two selector types are supported - `ComponentRef` and `ref`-variable.

Comment: thanks, but the question is specific to accessing them _using `@ViewChildren`_, as I stated in my question. This is specifically to not break level of abstraction. I'll upvote anyways

Comment: thanks, it'd be great to see the implementation of querying process

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I think this is the query code : https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/view_compiler/query_binder.ts#L18